# Mass Download with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, url, download

I am a basic python coder and I am trying create a python program where I can insert a url from a specific website. It will go through various links on the website and download all the pdf files from that specific site. I used Google Chrome. I searched the Internet for some good ways to do this and I ripped this specific code. I tried the code out on PyCharm.

```
def getPageHtmlSourceCode(url):
    try:
        import urllib2

        request_headers = {
            "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0",
            "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
            "Referer": "http://thewebsite.com",
            "Connection": "keep-alive"
        }

        request = urllib2.Request(url, headers=request_headers)
        return urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
    except:
        return "error"

def inputUrl():
    url = "http://www.4ono.com/cbse-12th-science-previous-year-question-papers-pdf-201617/"
    htmlSourceCode = getPageHtmlSourceCode(url);
    if htmlSourceCode != "error":
        return htmlSourceCode
    print("\nCouldn't connect to web, please check the url entered or try again later\n")

def crawlPage(htmlSourceCode):
    start = 0
    while (1):
        subjectNameStart = htmlSourceCode.find('<h2 id="', start)
        if subjectNameStart < 0:
            break
        subjectNameEnd = htmlSourceCode.find('"', subjectNameStart + 8)
        subjectName = htmlSourceCode[subjectNameStart + 8:subjectNameEnd - 1]
        # my_file = open("output.txt", "a")
        # my_file.write(subjectName + '\n')
        # my_file.close()
        # print(subjectName)
        newSubSection = htmlSourceCode.find('<h2 id="', subjectNameEnd)
        subSectionEnd = subjectNameEnd
        while (subSectionEnd < newSubSection):
            stateStart = htmlSourceCode.find('<p><strong>', subjectNameEnd)
            stateEnd = htmlSourceCode.find('</strong>', stateStart + 11)
            state = htmlSourceCode[stateStart + 11:stateEnd]
            subjectNameEnd = stateEnd
            if subSectionEnd > newSubSection:
                break
            # my_file = open("output.txt", "a")
            # my_file.write(state + '\n')
            # my_file.close()
            newStateSection = htmlSourceCode.find('<p><strong>', stateEnd + 7)
            stateSectionEnd = stateEnd
            while (1):
                pdfLinkStart = htmlSourceCode.find('<a href="', stateEnd)
                subSectionEnd = pdfLinkStart
                pdfLinkEnd = htmlSourceCode.find('.pdf">', pdfLinkStart + 9)
                pdfLink = htmlSourceCode[pdfLinkStart + 9:pdfLinkEnd + 4]
                yearEnd = htmlSourceCode.find("</a>", pdfLinkEnd + 4)
                year = htmlSourceCode[pdfLinkEnd + 6:yearEnd]
                stateEnd = yearEnd
                stateSectionEnd = yearEnd
                pdfName = subjectName + '-' + state + '-' + year + '.pdf'
                import urllib
                urllib.urlretrieve(pdfLink, pdfName)
                if stateSectionEnd > newStateSection:
                    break
            # my_file = open("output.txt", "a")
            # my_file.write(year + '\n')
            # my_file.write(pdfLink + '\n')
            # my_file.close()
            # print(pdfLink)
            # print(year)
        start = subjectNameEnd

def lookUp():
    htmlSourceCode = inputUrl()
    crawlPage(htmlSourceCode)
```

The results for the code is as followed:

```
"C:\Users\Pyro\PycharmProjects\PDF Downloader\venv\Scripts\python.exe" C:/Users/Pyro/.PyCharmCE2019.1/config/scratches/scratch.py

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: you define functions but you never execute them in code - so program makes nothing and it exits.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to call the `lookup()` function for it to work.
Add the following line at the very end of you code.

```py
lookup()
```